# How to put random characters into a multi dimentional array in C

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to build a board of 4X4 and I'm trying to use the rand function to put random characters in the board.
I need 8 pairs of characters and I don't want to have more than one pair of the same char.
how should I do it?.. I tried a lot of variations without success.

Please help.

Comment: Post the code you tried, we might be able to spot the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure my answer is what you exactly want. I hope it will be helpful.

It looks like your question is more like a algorithm issue. Let's say you are trying to find 8 unique random character pairs and each pair contains two different characters.

Then you can do as following:

1. Get all possible characters you may use, for instance A ~ Z.
2. Create one array and its value is a unique character pair which has two characters you want to use. You can use a nested loop to do it.
3. Record how many elements you have in the array. Assume the value is N.
4. Use function rand() and number N to get one random number r1.
5. Pick up the value at position r1 of array and put it into your board.
6. Switch this element with the last element of array.
7. Use function rand() and number N-1 to get one random numbe r2. Then do step 5, 6 again.
8. Do it as step 4 to step 7 to get all 8 pair you want.

If you just want to get 16 unique characters, then just ignore step 2 but keep an array which has all possible characters.

If you want to some weird character, such as '$', '%', etc, then use ASC values.